# How to get API data from MS Health Band in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, api, microsoft-band

I am trying to get the real time data from MS Health Band to perform analysis in MATLAB. I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/MS%20Health%20API%20Getting%20Started.pdf), but I can't figure out how to implement this in MATLAB. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get real time (sensor) data from a **Microsoft Band**, then it's not the MS Health API, but the **[Microsoft Band SDK](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK)** that you'll need. It includes functions to enable sensors and receive streaming data.

This SDK exists only for **Windows** (C#), **Android** (Java) and **iOS** (Objective C). There is no MATLAB library. If you need to process the data in real time, one thing you could try is to write an application (using one of these libraries), that writes the incoming sensor data **to a file**, that is read and processed by your MATLAB code.

Comment: That makes sense. If I do not have experience in any of the above programming languages, what would you suggest. The link that I posted above talks about the API, can't that be called directly in MATLAB? or would I need to use something like Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: Hi, I have been able to run the Microsoft Band SDK, but I am having to run each sensor individually, should I write an app to record all the data simultaneously? Once, how should I stream real time data to MATLAB?

Comment: @DashD - To make it clear, processing real time data coming from the Band in MATLAB is not straightforward. The easiest way would probably be to write an application in C# on Windows 10 running on a PC (so MATLAB runs on the same machine), that connects to the Band. (I have only worked with the Band SDK for Android, so I'm not familiar with the Windows one.) You should be able to subscribe to all sensors at the same time in the beginning, and write the incoming numbers to a .CSV file on disk. In MATLAB, you could monitor this file, and if any change occurs, read the last line and process it.